# SCRIPT 600 Error : Invalid target element for this operation

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a php site that works fine in FireFox and Chrome, but breaks completly in IE.

Here is just one of the scripts that is throwing an error...
SCRIPT600: Invalid target element for this operation.

```
function loadDeals() {
    $.get("modules/recommendations/viewrecommendations.php",{},function(response){
        document.getElementById("dealdata").innerHTML = response;
    });
}
```

It throws the error on the line that sets the innerHTML...Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: What is the element with id `dealdata`?

Comment: If you already use jQuery, then why not for that too? `$('#dealdata').html(response)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: are you using jquery?

also looks like you have an extra set of brackets in there (i think between `,{},`)

```
function loadDeals() {
    $.get("modules/recommendations/viewrecommendations.php",function(response){
        $("#dealdata").html(response);
    });
}
```

Comment: The `{}` is just sending a blank object as GET parameters, it shouldn't break anything.

Comment: I did not know that though that is good to know for future debugging.

Answer (score 13):

IE has a problem replacing TBODY contents with innerHTML. The jQuery given above works; if you are not using jQuery, another solution is to have a `<div id='helper' style='visibility:hidden'/>` somewhere in the page - when the response arrives, put the value with a surrounding `<table>` tag into the hidden div, then use the DOM to remove the old contents from your visible tag and insert the elements from the hidden tag 1 by 1:

```
var a=document.getElementById("dealdata");

while(a.firstChild!=null)
  a.removeChild(a.firstChild);

var b=document.getElementById("helper");
b.innerHTML="<table>"+this.responseText+"</table>";
while(b.tagName!="TR") {
  if(b.tagName==null)
    b=b.nextSibling;
  else
    b=b.firstChild;
}
for(;b!=null;b=b.nextSibling)
  a.appendChild(b);
```

Comment: To All: If you're running into this error in ASP.NET MVC with "Ajax.BeginForm" - most likely "UpdateTargetId" is a table. Add a surrounding DIV and change the "UpdateTargetId" accordingly.